# Groupby greater than in Pandas very slow

Tags: python, pandas

I have the table below as a pandas dataframe. I need count of all `Part Number` where `Net Sales` is greater than `Recommended Price` for a given part.

**Input: above_master**

```
  Short Number  Net Sales    Part Number   Recommended Price
0       MU2146     413.25      MU2146      385.949155
1       MU2146     433.12      MU2146      385.949155
2       MU2146     498.12      MU2146      385.949155
3       MU1609     146.07      MU1609      149.138978
4       MU1609     246.17      MU1609      149.138978
```

**Required Output**

```
Part Number count
MU2146       3 
MU1609       1
```

**Code Used**

```
for number in range(len(above_master.index)):
    cal_s1 = above_master[above_master['Net Sales'] > above_master.iloc[number]['Recommended Price'] ].groupby('Part Number')['Recommended Price'].count()
    cal_s2 = cal_s1.to_frame().reset_index()
    cal_s3 = cal_s2.loc[cal_s2['Part Number'] == above_master.iloc[number]['Part Number']]
    cal_s4 = cal_s4.append(cal_s3, ignore_index=True)
```

This works fine but it takes very long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `loc` with `size`:

```
df.loc[df['Recommended Price'].lt(df['Net Sales'])].groupby('Part Number').size()
```

```
Part Number
MU1609    1
MU2146    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the logical comparison first using [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html)(Greater Than) assign it to `count` column, then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) using `Part Number` with parameter `as_index=False` then access the `count` sum on it as:

```
df['count'] = df['Net Sales'].gt(df['Recommended Price'])
df.groupby(['Part Number'],as_index=False)['count'].sum()

  Part Number  count
0      MU1609    1.0
1      MU2146    3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using pandas Series value_counts

```
df['Part Number'][df['Recommended Price'] < df['Net Sales']].value_counts()
```